# BASH - How to check for duplicate email addresses across multiple files?

Tags: bash, email, split, unique, chunks

I'm currently working on a project where I need to send an email to a large number of email addresses. As such I am attempting to avoid any "temporary" glitches with respect to service providers throttling emails etc.

My plan is to take the initial list of email addresses and chop it up into smaller (chopped) lists, so that they can be scheduled in a staggered manner. Due to the sensitive nature of sending emails, I want to ensure that no duplicate email addresses exist across any of the chopped lists. Is there a way to do this via bash?

Side note, I am 100% certain that all email addresses in the master list are unique, due to the nature of the query used to comprise the list, I would just like to ensure, my script which chopped the master list, does not have a defect creating duplicate email addresses across the chopped lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the chopped files together (temporarily) via cat and use sort --unique to remove duplicates - then check if the result has as many lines as the original file:

```
cat original_list | wc -l
```

and

```
cat list_part* | sort --unique | wc -l
```

if the results are same there are no duplicates.

Comment: Useless use of *cat*. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Redirection. Both *sort* and *wc* will accept globs or redirection as input.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 cat *.txt | sort | sort -u -c
```

given that your filenames are ending with .txt.
The first sort command orders all email addresses. The second sort command checks that no two consecutive lines are equal and throws an error in the other case.

Comment: Nice, I ended up going with timos solution, due to the fact that I can directly compare the counts.

Comment: Used your solution as well to track down a duplicate. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Problem

You need to sort unique addresses, and then split the ordered list into chunks.

#### The Solution

Given the following assumptions:

1. Your emails are stored in files called **emails_xxxx.txt**. (Note: You can name them anything you like, but a sensible set of filenames that are easy to glob will make your life simpler.)
2. Each line holds one address.

you can handle this with a short pipeline. *Sort* will accept a glob pattern or multiple file arguments (e.g. from *xargs*), so you can avoid the "useless use of cat." You then pipe the output into *split*, where you can control various aspects of the chunking. For example:

```
sort --unique emails_*.txt |
split --numeric-suffixes \
      --lines=200 \ 
      --suffix-length=4 \
      --verbose
```

This splits the sorted/filtered lines into chunks of up to 200 lines each, and names each chunk with a numeric extension suitable for batch processing. You can adjust the lines and suffix length to suit your requirements.

#### Sample Output

```
creating file `x0000'
creating file `x0001'
```

Comment: I'm not trying to split the master list into smaller lists, that work is already done. I am simply validating that no duplicates were created due to the split.

Comment: @MikePurcell Understood...but then you have to handle the exceptions. Why not just insert a shim that won't generate errors or exceptions in the first place? I'm glad the other answer worked for you, but I'm going to leave this for others who may find it useful.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "handle the exceptions". The algorithm I wrote to generate the chop files is flexible enough to  vary the sizes of the resulting chop files. For example, the first two chop files should contain only 2K emails, whereas the next two chop files can be 10K, finally ramping up to 50K email addresses per chop file.

Comment: @MikePurcell By "exceptions," I mean the cases where data validation fails. It just seems better to me to prevent a known error condition, rather than detecting it with data validation and then doing something about it *post facto*. This is definitely "your mileage may vary" territory, but I'd be happy to continue the discussion in chat or on Twitter.